# Redirect input to a file descriptor?

Tags: bash, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I wrote a script `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
#test.sh

echo "This is important message" > /dev/tty
```

When I tried executing on `bash`

```
./test.sh
```

> This is important message

I usually don't like messages on the terminal

```
./test.sh  > /dev/null
```

Okay, the output never went to standard output

> This is important message

That is pretty annoying. I really don't like a few messages that are deliberately dumped onto the terminal. Hence, this is what I did.

```
exec 3<> /dev/tty
./test.sh > /dev/null 3>&1    #Send whatever comes to /dev/tty(3) to /dev/null
```

But that doesn't work as expected.

> This is important message

So what is going wrong? How am I supposed to disappear the output? I really don't want the script to hold my terminal hostage.

Comment: Why do you echo message to **tty** from inside the script? Why not making that line just  `echo "This is important message"` then control output from shell.

Comment: From within a script, I've used `eval "./test.sh &> ./test_command.log` before to reroute output from the console window to the text file, `test_command.log`. Have you tried inserting a `&` before your `>`? By the way, there's a really good explanation of all of the different possibilities for I/O rerouting [TLDP guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Comment: @VladislavMartin That doesn't reroute output headed to the console window; the `eval` is unnecessary and it just reroutes both standard output and standard error (both of which may have *previously* been attached to the console) to a file.

Comment: @chepner it reroutes standard output/error, as you said. What output does it not reroute to the console window? Also, I guess `eval` is necessary but just as an explanation, in my code I had used that command followed by `&  PIDTX=$!` to run two commands simultaneously from the same script... didn't think about removing it because it'll work with or without.

Comment: It does not reroute output that is written *directly* to /dev/tty, rather than to file descriptor 1.

Comment: @DJack `exec 3<>  /dev/tty` only determines which file is bound to file descriptor 3; it does not affect attempts to write to `/dev/tty` via other file descriptors.

Comment: @Kadir Let's just say the script is given likewise. You can't change the script. I can only run it and expect not to see any output.

Comment: @chepner Are you saying that fd #3 keeps waiting fruitlessly for output through its file stream while the output is sent to the file(i.e. /dev/tty) through another stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "This is important message" > /dev/tty
```

That's saying, "output to the tty". You can't redirect the tty itself. You need to change your script instead.

(The only possible way to inhibit output with the script as it stands is to make it run with a controlling terminal that doesn't output; eg. a pseudo-terminal whose output is consumed by the master. <strike>There aren't any general-purpose tools I'm aware of to do this</strike> see below).

Your question implies a misunderstanding in how redirection works / what it does. The lines you wrote in the shell don't do what you seem to think:

```
exec 3<> /dev/tty
```

This redirects the #3 file descriptor (which isn't normally associated with anything anyway) to the controlling terminal.

```
./test.sh > /dev/null 3>&1    #Send whatever comes to /dev/tty(3) to /dev/null
```

No; it sends whatever is directed to file descriptor #3 to the current target of file descriptor #1 (which is /dev/null). But that won't affect your script which expressly sends a message to the tty device (controlling terminal, which would normally be the terminal you ran the command from). Specifically, the `echo` command in the script outputs to stdout (file descriptor #1) which, for that command, is redirected to `/dev/tty`, i.e. the controlling terminal.

**Using socat to change the controlling terminal**

You can use the "socat" program to change the controlling terminal to a pseudoterminal and redirect the master output to /dev/null, with a command line similar to the following:

`socat EXEC:./test.sh,pty,setsid /dev/null`

The socat program connects an input sink/output source to another input sink/output source. In this case, it connects the specified program's input/out to /dev/null, via a pseudo terminal ("pty" option) which is made the controlling terminal ("setsid" option).

Comment: There's no way the script can be changed. Assume it is given to me. Only a peek into it reveals the said lines.

Comment: Also I dont want to redirect tty itself. I want to redirect any and all possible outputs sent to tty. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "pseudo-terminal whose output is consumed by the master" ? Can you elaborate it, please?

Comment: I mean that a pseudo-terminal slave/master pair could be created by some process, the slave could be made the controlling terminal of the script, and the master side (which receives input from the slave, i.e it receives what the slave outputs) could be simply consumed rather than output. See [pty(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pty) for information. As I said, I'm not aware of any existing tool that will do this for you; you might need to write your own.

Comment: Regarding whether output sent to tty can be redirected, strictly speaking the answer is no - output goes where it sent. The question is where output sent to `/dev/tty` goes - it goes to the _controlling terminal_, and it's not impossible to change the controlling terminal.

Comment: @Djack thanks for accepting, I've updated the answer after discovering that `socat` might do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating file descriptor to /dev/null, do echo, then close file descriptor.

```
#!/bin/bash
#test.sh

exec 5<> /dev/null
echo "This is important message" >&5
exec 5>&-
```

Test run of script and results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect output to any of the virtual console, if you have `root` access. just like this.

```
echo "This is important message" > /dev/tty1
```